# How to plot text with ggplot2::annotate() such that it's formatted like cat()

Tags: r, ggplot2

(Up-Front-Remark: I am happy to change and edit this post, as I know how important that is, so please excuse and criticise me if something should be changed to make this post better.)

I want to plot text only with ggplot2::annotate(). The string of text has special characters ('\n', '\t').

The string I want to plot:

```
txttest <- "MSSubClass: Identifies the type of dwelling involved in the sale\n\n        20\t1-STORY 1946 & NEWER ALL STYLES\n        30\t1-STORY 1945 & OLDER\n        40\t1-STORY W/FINISHED ATTIC ALL AGES\n        45\t1-1/2 STORY - UNFINISHED ALL AGES\n        50\t1-1/2 STORY FINISHED ALL AGES\n        60\t2-STORY 1946 & NEWER\n        70\t2-STORY 1945 & OLDER\n        75\t2-1/2 STORY ALL AGES\n        80\tSPLIT OR MULTI-LEVEL\n        85\tSPLIT FOYER\n        90\tDUPLEX - ALL STYLES AND AGES\n       120\t1-STORY PUD (Planned Unit Development) - 1946 & NEWER\n       150\t1-1/2 STORY PUD - ALL AGES\n       160\t2-STORY PUD - 1946 & NEWER\n       180\tPUD - MULTILEVEL - INCL SPLIT LEV/FOYER\n       190\t2 FAMILY CONVERSION - ALL STYLES AND AGES\n\n"
```

When plotting it with `cat()` I get the following:

> ```
> MSSubClass: Identifies the type of dwelling involved in the sale
>
>     20    1-STORY 1946 & NEWER ALL STYLES
>     30    1-STORY 1945 & OLDER
>     40    1-STORY W/FINISHED ATTIC ALL AGES
>     45    1-1/2 STORY - UNFINISHED ALL AGES
>     50    1-1/2 STORY FINISHED ALL AGES
>     60    2-STORY 1946 & NEWER
>     70    2-STORY 1945 & OLDER
>     75    2-1/2 STORY ALL AGES
>     80    SPLIT OR MULTI-LEVEL
>     85    SPLIT FOYER
>     90    DUPLEX - ALL STYLES AND AGES
>    120    1-STORY PUD (Planned Unit Development) - 1946 & NEWER
>    150    1-1/2 STORY PUD - ALL AGES
>    160    2-STORY PUD - 1946 & NEWER
>    180    PUD - MULTILEVEL - INCL SPLIT LEV/FOYER
>    190    2 FAMILY CONVERSION - ALL STYLES AND AGES
> ```

(Remark: MSSubClass:.. is indented with 4 spaces. In real R the 'MSSubClass:...' is a little more to the left compared to the rest of the text.)

When using `ggplot2::annotate()` I need to use `base::paste()` for `label` instead of `base::cat()`. Not sure exactly why. I figure because `cat()` and `paste()` do not create the same type of output.

Therefore I get the following code:

```
ggplot() + annotate("text",x = 3,y = 25,size = 3,
                              label = paste(txttest)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()
    )
```

This code produces the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVOyy.jpg).

I tried to make the text flush-left with `hjust = 0`:

```
ggplot() + annotate("text",x = 3,y = 25,size = 3,
                              label = paste(txttest), hjust = 0) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()
    )
```

creating [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDUsu.jpg).
That has correct formatting but weird 'spacing'. And adjusting the value for *hjust* does not solve the issue.

How can I plot the text *formatted correctly* (similar to the output of `base::cat()`) and *centered* (contrary to the option with `hjust = 0`)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and thought I'd leave this post in case others might want to do the same thing.

Simply add `hjust = 0, xmax = 4`, which aligns the text to the left and also sets a text-limit to the right.